# PMD/CPD can't detect duplicate code

Tags: maven, pmd, cpd

I am new to `PMD/CPD`. I have configured `PMD` in my maven project as below:

```xml
<groupId>org.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>CustRestExampleOsgi</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>CustRestExampleOsgii</name>

<modules>
    <module>CustImplProvider</module>
    <module>CustInterface</module>
    <module>RestCustConsumer</module>
</modules>

<properties>
<karaf.deploy.build.folder>
    G:\apache-karaf-3.0.0.RC1\deploy
</karaf.deploy.build.folder>
</properties>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

My maven project is compiling normally and generating all reports by **`mvn jxr:jxr site`**. 
But I am unable to find any result which shows duplicate code. To test this I have introduced duplicate code intentionally in my code, as:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Address)) {
        return false;
    }
    Address other = (Address) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null)
      || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(object instanceof Address)) { //Duplicate is here
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But always `CPD` shows no problem detected in the source code. However I can find `PMD` reports normally. Am I missing some configuration or ruleset?

Kindly help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you set the minimum token count low enough. Your short piece of duplicate code has fewer tokens than the default 100.

According to [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/cpd-mojo.html#minimumTokens), the property is called `minimumTokens`. Older versions of the Maven PMD plugin had a property `maven.pmd.cpd.minimumtokencount`. Set it to 5 for testing. In real life, the default of 100 is a good value.